# How to implement a generic Thrift Proxy?

Tags: rpc, thrift

In Apache Thrift is it possible to create a generic proxy? For e.g. in proxy I want to do request/response logging or measure performance. The flow should be like Client <-> Generic Proxy <-> Server for all RPC calls.

Comment: Note to close-voters: That question is not really about server infrastructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement an custom Thrift "layered" protocol or a custom Thrift transport which intercepts your calls as needed.

A lot of languages have adopted the [multiplexed protocol](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1915) which uses a generic [`TProtocolDecorator`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TProtocolDecorator.h). That piece of code looks quite handy for that task. Look at the [implementation of `TMultiplexedProtocol`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TMultiplexedProtocol.cpp) to see how it's used. Basically the `TProtocolDecorator` class does most of the magic, you only need to override some methods and plug your newly developed protocol into the Thrift transport/protocol stack as usual.

Alternatively, your goal could be achieved by adding a layered transport, similar to [`TBufferedTransport`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h). But in that case you do not have the semantics behind the data, you only see strings whereas at the protocol level you have methods like  `WriteMessageBegin` or `ReadMessageBegin` which make live much easier.

Comment: If I use the multiplexed protocol, my proxy isn't generic anymore, isn't it? I need to register all processors in this case.

Comment: I mentioned the multiplex protocol as an **example**. I did not recommend to use multiplex in your code, that would not help you much here. Instead you want use it as a blueprint for some own protocol that you want to develop on top of the `TProtocolDecorator` to meet your goals.