# How to auto logging of every thrift request method and parameters?

Tags: logging, thrift, auto-generate

I know how to use thrift to autogenerate c++ methods but don't know how to make thrift autogenerate c++ statements that log every thrift request and its parameters.

I have googled for a while but still found no answer. Does anyone happen to know the how-to?

Comment: There is `TServerEventHandler` but it may not be exactly what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a generic Thrift Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607830/how-to-implement-a-generic-thrift-proxy)